# Oscillation of a spring and added mass

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring, elasticity

Why do we need to add a mass to a spring to make a simple harmonic motion in it? Why can't only a spring 'without a mass' make a simple harmonic motion when we apply an external force?

Comment: If you have the means to read a Mathematica notebook, you can check this out https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/7773/ to see the additional complexities of having a massive spring.  Low level physics courses do not assume the student has experience solving partial differential equations.

Answer (score 4):

Because the mass of spring is distributed along the spring, the motion will not be harmonic, but more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason, really. It's just to provide students with a simple, clear, metaphor.

In fact any physical system in which the strength applied varies at least in a fist approximation linearly with a distance or angle or generalised coordinate will follow the pattern:

$$m\ddot{x}+kx=0$$

So, basically, all mechanical systems enter into that category for small amplitude movements.

1. A pendulum.
2. A guitar String.
3. A vibrating membrane.

The reason behind the ubiquity of this pattern is found in Taylors's development formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series (for x small: $f (x) \sim k \cdot x)$

Answer (score -1):

Because the Newtonian equation of motion of a spring-mass system is:

$$m\ddot{x}+kx=0$$

which is the ODE of a harmonic oscillator, with solution:

$$x(t)=A\sin\left(\omega t+\varphi\right)$$

where $\omega^2=\frac{k}{m}$.

Comment: Why the downvote, please?